# ModelForm is creating a new record inspite of providing an instance

Tags: python, html, django

I am creating a ToDo list where I can create a ToDo item and provide a button against each item to update it. I am using ModelForm to save my data to DB.
The update button takes me to 'update.html' with the instance of selected task. But when I update the task information and click on 'Submit', it creates a new task with the updated information and does not update the same task.
Please help me, I am stuck.

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import Task
from .forms import *

def index(request):
    tasks = Task.objects.all()
    form = TaskForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TaskForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        return redirect('/')
    else:
        context = {'tasks':tasks,'form':form}
        return render(request,'TaskList/list.html',context)

def update(request, pk):

    task = Task.objects.get(id = pk)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TaskForm(request.POST, instance=task)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/')   
    else:
        form = TaskForm(instance = task)
        context = {'task':task, 'form':form}
        return render(request,'TaskList/update.html', context)
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name = 'list'),
    path('update/<str:pk>/', views.update, name = 'update')
]
```

update.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method = 'POST' action = ''>
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form}}
        <input type = 'submit' name = 'Update'>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

list.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>ToDoList</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method = 'POST' action = ''>
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form.title}}
        <input type = 'submit' name = 'Create Task'>
    </form>
    {% for task in tasks %}
        <div>
            <a href = "{% url 'update' task.id %}">Update</a>
            <p>{{task.title}}</p>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The `action` contains `'update/<str:pk>/update'`, wich is an invalid action.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to erase that while posting. I have edited the code. But still I am facing the same problem

Comment: are you sure you are triggering the correct view? Can you add `print` statements, to see if you submit your form, that it is passed to the correct view?

Comment: I added a print statement just before saving the form in 'index' method, data is being passed to the correct view

Comment: but the `index` method will indeed create a new record. The question was, if I understood it correctly, why it is not updating, but creating a record. If you want to update the record, you need to make a POST request to the `update` view.

Comment: I also added a print statement in 'update' method to see if the call goes to the correct view while updating, so when I submit from 'list.html', index method is being called and when I submit from 'update.html', 'update' method is being called using 'POST'.

Comment: What if you use `<form method="POST" action="{% url 'update' task.pk %}">` in the update form (with double quotes, and no spaces between `method` and `"POST"`, etc., since that is not HTML compliant).

Comment: I made these two changes and it worked!!Thank you so much, before this I was just stuck here with no help. But not sure what made it work, removing the spaces or changing the action. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

here u are again saving the form which creates a new record(in update function).
instead try to get the object from db like

```
form_object = <model_name>.objects.get(id = id)
form_object.<parameter_to_be_updated> = <the value you want>
form_object.save()
```